# data-bind not working in List View template within Grid detail template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-listview

I need help using a Kendo UI list view which lives within a grid row detail template.
here is something I have done so far.

```
<div id="grid">
        </div>

 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="gridDetailTemplate">
            <div class='grid-edit'>
                <div class='edit-list'></div>
            </div>
        </script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="editItemtemplate">
            <div class='edit-Item'>
            #if(Type=='string'){#
            <ul><li><b>#:Name#</b></li><li><input class='inputString' value='#:DataVal()#'/></li></ul>
            #}else if(Type=='number'){#
            <ul><li><b>#:Name#</b></li><li><input class='inputNumber' data-role='numerictextbox' data-type='number' value='#:DataVal()#'/></li></ul>
            #}else if(Type=='date'){#
            <ul><li><b>#:Name#</b></li><li><input class='inputDate' data-role='datepicker' value='#:kendo.toString(DataVal(),'MM/dd/yyyy')#'/></li></ul>
            #}else if(Type=='boolean'){Name #<input type='checkbox'/>
            #}#
            </div>
        </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $.get("http://localhost:4916/DataAttribute", function (data, status) {
                    var selFields = new Object();
                    $.each(data, function (index, elem) {
                        selFields[elem.Name] = new Object();
                        selFields[elem.Name]["type"] = elem.Type;
                    });
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: { url: "http://localhost:4916/Deal",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                }
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: "Data", total: "Total",
                                model: {

                                    fields: selFields
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        height: 430,
                        filterable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: false,
                        detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#gridDetailTemplate").html()),
                        detailInit: detailInit,
                        columns: [{
                            field: "SecurityName",
                            title: "Security Name",
                            width: 250
                        },
                            {
                                field: "DateOfAcquisition",
                                title: "Date Of Acquisition",
                                width: 120,
                                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                            }, {
                                field: "Acres",
                                title: "Acres",
                                width: 120
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
            });


            function detailInit(e) {
                $.get("http://localhost:4916/DataAttribute", function (data, status) {
                    var detailRow = e.detailRow;

                    detailRow.find(".edit-list").kendoListView({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: data,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    DataVal: function () {
                                        switch (this.get("Type")) {
                                        case "number"
                                        }
                                        if (e.data[this.get("Name")])
                                            return e.data[this.get("Name")];
                                        else
                                            return '';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        template: kendo.template($("#editItemtemplate").html())
                    });
                });
            }


        </script>
```

My code gets dynamic field list and binds it to the data source for grid.
Then, in the detailInit event, I find the div within row detail and convert it into kendo UI list, for which the template have been created.

Now, when I use `data-bind="value: DataVal()"` ,it doesn't pick up the values of List data source. It works the way I have done i.e. `value="#: DataVal() #"`. But, data-role does not convert the fields to specified types which are datepicker and numericinput in my case.

I believe that data-role not being used is caused due to same issue as data-bind not being read.

Can anyone help me out with this? Also, feel free to suggest any alternate ways and general code improvements. I am an ASP.NET developer and usually don't work on pure html and javascript.

PS: I would be happy to provide the context on what I am trying to achieve here if anyone is interested.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rig up a jsFiddle or jsBin example that would help debug the issue.

However, try removing the parenthesis:

```
data-bind="value: DataVal"
```

Kendo should detect that `DataVal` is a function and call it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar situation in a listview template. I created a JSFiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/zacharydl/7L3SL/

Oddly, the solution is to **wrap the contents of the template in a div**. It looks like your template already has this, so YMMV.

```html
<div id="example">
    <div data-role="listview" data-template="template" data-bind="source: array"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <!--<div>-->
        <div>method 1: #:field#</div>
        <div>method 2: <span data-bind="text: field"></span></div>
        <input data-role="datepicker" />
    <!--</div>-->
</script>
```

```js
var model = kendo.observable({
    array: [
        { field: 'A'},
        { field: 'B'}
    ]
});

kendo.bind($('#example'), model);
```